# Change label string Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have a SQL query in the python script of my Odoo module and I want to change the label string with the field value in the Python file.
I have spent so much time and I haven't find a solution. 
Is this possible?

Python

```
 class families (models.Model):
   _name = 'families.f'
   button = fields.Char("")
   txt = fields.Char()

   @api.one
   def on_change_label(self):
     mydb = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','xxx','xxx','xxx')
     cursor=mydb.cursor()
     cursor.execute("MyQuery")
       for row in cursor:
              "change the string content of the label with the row value"
```

In my XML I have a label tag inside form tag, like this:

```
<label name="on_change_label" for="txt"/>
```

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: Have you tried so far ? Share your efforts in your question.

Comment: Manu W. I updated the question with the code. Thanks!

Comment: Label and Value are 2 columns in the view. You can use 2 fields (Field1-Value and Field2-Value) instead of Label and Value.

Comment: in the table `ir.model.field` you will find the field of models and the label

Comment: For that active your developer mode and go to `setting/technical/database structure/fields`

Comment: Thanks Anonymous miliana but my question refers to an external MySQL database, and I want to show the result of the query in an label.

Comment: julivico, I think that you have the solution, but I don't quite understand your solution; you want to say key:value ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem : in Odoo, you have a field which has a label (mostly the string parameter of the field). And you have a MySQL database in which you wish to store the value of that field when it changes (because labels do not change over time). So ... where is the problem ? Or what you really want to do is that the value of a field will be the label of another field ? That last one is possible and does not require any SQL shenanigan.